# Question on templates

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, page-template

I'm using a free theme called Ocean WP that has a folder called 'templates'

I thought I could just save over one of the templates and rename it and construct a template (which I need for custom post types/ Advanced Custom Fields).

However when I tried the above it threw an error.

My question is - what should I be looking for with regards to building templates.

Of course the easiest way to build a template is to just copy the page.php and give it a new name but that seems to be the wrong approach given that there is a folder called 'templates'

Thanks for all direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder is just where Ocean WP's developers chose to store its templates. It's not something for you to do anything with. If you want to create your own custom template you need to create a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and create the template there. If you create or modify files in a theme they will be erased if/when the theme is updated. Creating a Child Theme avoids this issue.

Regarding the error, putting a file into a theme wouldn't throw an error on its own. You likely had a syntax error in the code of the template.